# How to make mobs attack other players, but not me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a minigame where I will have a spider that doesn't attack me, but attacks the other players. I know that I can use teams to turn off friendly fire, but the problem is that everyone is already in a team, because we want the nicks disabled. A player can't be in two teams at the same time and if I turn off friendly fire the spider won't attack anyone.

How can I make a spider that attack everyone but me without using teams?

Answer (score -1):

Add them to your team by giving them a nametag, then using the `/team` command to add them to your team.

Comment: I didn't understand